# Send files with sftp then delete afterwards one line?

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

How can I send files using `sftp` then delete them afterwards?

I have managed to get this far with sending all files with a set extension from a directory,

```
sftp user@remote <<< $'put -r /path/to/file/test_file/*.json'
```

but how can I *delete* them once I have sent them and only if they have been successfully sent on the one line command?

Also, the server I am using is very locked down, so I won't be able to install additional software from the internet and could this be kept as a one line send. This will also be used with cron, hence using one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it in one line, use `&&` operator:

```
sftp user@remote <<< $'put -r /path/to/file/test_file/*.json' && rm /path/to/file/test_file/*.json
```

It will execute `rm` only if `sftp` has succeeded. Adding [`-b -`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#b) to `sftp` is probably a good idea (if not necessary).